# Is there an NPAPI Chrome Extension that can handle input from six Xbox 360 controllers?

Tags: html, google-chrome, npapi, xbox360, joystick

I'm working on creating an HTML5 game designed for six players and I would like to include Xbox 360 controller support. Is there an existing browser plugin that enables JavaScript to access up to six Xbox controllers?

If none exists how would I go about creating one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of an existing plugin that does that; If you want to write your own, I suggest you look at [FireBreath](http://www.firebreath.org). Basically you'll need to figure out how to interface with the controller and then you can set up a FireBreath plugin to fire events when certain events occur on the controller, i.e. buttons and movement.

FireBreath plugins work as NPAPI plugins and also as ActiveX controls, so they will work on IE as well as chrome, firefox, and safari.

Answer (score 0):

There wasn't before, but there is now: [Boomstick](https://github.com/STRd6/Boomstick). Boomstick provides native joystick support to JavaScript for up to 8 joysticks. It's currently in development, but is close to running on every major browser and platform.